# How to check if a Mobile Number Authenticated user already exists in our firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, authentication

How to check if a Mobile Number(user) already exists in our `Firebase` Project's list of authenticated users, in Android? 
P.S. I know the `fetchProvidersForEmail` method exists for email authenticated users but cannot find an equivalent method for phone number authenticated users.

Comment: There is nothing like "mobile number authentication" type of sign-in using firebase authentication. However, what your looking for can be achieved using rest api. Check this website for a guide on achieving something similar: https://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-12-2/

Comment: That doesn't seem a good option if there are thousands of users. We would have to download all the users' credentials and traverse through the whole data to check for a particular user. Is there any better alternative in your knowledge? @codeFreak

Comment: You don't need to download anything. MYSQL database sorts using the variable sent by the app to authenticate the user. In your case a mobile number and password.

Comment: Oh OK! But for that also, how do I get the URL of the users list, or how do I access the users in JSON format? @codeFreak